# How to disable zomming highstock chart on mobile

Tags: highcharts

I want to disable zooming highstock chart on mobile when somebody pinch on mobile browser like iPhone safari.

I tried setting all options, enableMouseTracking: false, zoomType: null, zoomType: 'none', pinchType: 'none', pinchType: null

But nothing works. As soon as I zoom gesture is performed it zooms-in the chart and show "Reset Zoom" button. I have scrollbar, navigator, rangeSelector disabled already (enable: false).

Please help.

Comment: There should be `pinchType: ''`, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/xf200dxz/

Comment: Thanks Pawel

I tried that already, but it didn't worked. Actually what happens is when I scroll on Safari and area visible is chart, it zooms out the chart and show reset zoom button. But it doesn't scroll the page. I want to disable this zooming.

Comment: Have you tried my demo? It works for me. Please, try again. Also, make sure you are using up-to-date version of Highcharts.

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks a ton! My bad, I was trying this property outside of chart object. It works!